# PCL font character data from donor TTF file?

Tags: printing, printer-control-language

Anyone know how to extract Character Descriptor and Data Format for
TrueType Fonts for PCL from donor ttf Files?

Comment: I might be able to help but I don't understand the question.  Can you restate or rephrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to extract the data using Freetype easily.